# Chrome Autofill Carrying Across Different Forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autofill, react-hooks

First off, I'm going to guess that I'm going about rendering the forms the wrong way. I think I just want to understand where I have gone wrong here?

I have two tabs, that pass back a prop to define what one is active.

This prop then renders either a login or sign up form.

I have a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/z3mx372jm?fontsize=14) that you will need to enter a email and password and click submit in Chrome. This will prompt you to save the password.

If you do the above, the inputs should autofill and when you navigate from login to sign up the email and password autofill now carries over to sign up and populates with the same detail, even the password to plain text.

How do I go about ensuring this does not occur? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my Component, you can view the whole App on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/z3mx372jm?fontsize=14)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import _ from "lodash";

import InputControl from "./InputControl";
import InputButton from "./InputButton";
import FormControl from "./FormControl";

const LoginCard = props => {
  const [hideContent, setHideContent] = useState(false);

  const [emailSignUpRef, setEmailSignUpRef] = useState("");
  const [firstNameSignUpRef, setFirstNameEmailSignUpRef] = useState("");
  const [surNameSignUpRef, setSurNameEmailSignUpRef] = useState("");

  let registerEmailInput = "";
  let firstNameInput = "";
  let surNameInput = "";
  let checkBoxSignUp = "";
  let signUpBtn = "";

  const scrollToEl = _.debounce(
    el =>
      window.scrollTo({
        top: el,
        behavior: "smooth"
      }),
    1000
  );

  const handleOnFocus = event => {
    scrollToEl(event.target);
    setEmailSignUpRef(registerEmailInput.value);
    setFirstNameEmailSignUpRef(firstNameInput.value);
    setHideContent(true);
  };

  const handleOnInput = () => {
    setEmailSignUpRef(registerEmailInput.value);
    setFirstNameEmailSignUpRef(firstNameInput.value);
  };

  const handleOnBlur = event => {
    const rl = event.relatedTarget;
    if (
      !(firstNameInput === rl) &&
      !(registerEmailInput === rl) &&
      !(checkBoxSignUp === rl) &&
      !(signUpBtn === rl)
    ) {
      setHideContent(
        !_.isEmpty(emailSignUpRef.trim()) ||
          !_.isEmpty(firstNameSignUpRef.trim())
      );
    }
  };

  const loginForm = (
    <FormControl>
      <InputControl
        autoComplete="off"
        type="text"
        name="emailAddress"
        placeholder="Email address"
        label="Email Address"
      />
      <InputControl
        autoComplete="off"
        type="password"
        name="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        label="Password"
      />
      <InputControl type="checkbox" name="email" label="Keep me logged in" />
      <InputButton buttonText="Login" type="submit" />
    </FormControl>
  );

  const registerForm = (
    <FormControl>
      <InputControl
        refProp={input => {
          registerEmailInput = input;
        }}
        onInput={handleOnInput}
        onFocus={handleOnFocus}
        onBlur={handleOnBlur}
        value={emailSignUpRef}
        autoComplete="off"
        type="text"
        name="emailAddressRegister"
        placeholder="Email address"
        label="Email Address"
      />
      <InputControl
        className={
          !hideContent ? "InputControl--hidden" : "InputControl--visible"
        }
        autoComplete="off"
        refProp={input => {
          firstNameInput = input;
        }}
        onInput={handleOnInput}
        onBlur={handleOnBlur}
        type="text"
        name="firstName"
        placeholder="First Name"
        label="First Name"
      />
      <InputControl
        className={
          !hideContent ? "InputControl--hidden" : "InputControl--visible"
        }
        autoComplete="off"
        refProp={input => {
          surNameInput = input;
        }}
        onInput={handleOnInput}
        onBlur={handleOnBlur}
        type="text"
        name="surName"
        placeholder="Surname"
        label="Surname"
      />
      <InputControl
        refProp={input => {
          checkBoxSignUp = input;
        }}
        type="checkbox"
        name="checkboxRegister"
        label={["I have read and agreed to the terms and conditions"]}
      />
      <InputButton
        refProp={input => {
          signUpBtn = input;
        }}
        buttonText="Sign Up"
        type="submit"
      />
    </FormControl>
  );

  return (
    <div className="LoginCard">
      <h2
        className={
          "LoginCard-title" + (hideContent ? " LoginCard-titleHidden" : "")
        }
      >
        {props.active === "login" ? "Login" : "Sign Up"}
      </h2>
      {props.active === "login" ? loginForm : registerForm}
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(LoginCard);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed this issue. It was due to not passing a `key` attribute on the `FormControl` component!

```
<FormControl key={"loginForm"}
```